# How to skip a BOOST unit test?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost

How can I skip a BOOST unit test?  I would like to programatically skip some of my unit tests depending on, (for instance) the platform on which I am executing them.  My current solution is:

```
#define REQUIRE_LINUX char * os_cpu = getenv("OS_CPU"); if ( os_cpu != "Linux-x86_64" ) return;

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(onlylinux) {
    REQUIRE_LINUX
    ...
    the rest of the test code.
}
```

(note that our build environment sets the variable OS_CPU).  This seems ugly and error-prone, and also like the silent skips could cause users to be skipping tests without knowing about it.

How can I cleanly skip boost unit tests based on arbitrary logic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of skipping them, you can prevent to register them.
To achieve that you can use the manual test registration of boost.test:

```
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>
using namespace boost::unit_test;

//____________________________________________________________________________//

void only_linux_test()
{
    ...
}

//____________________________________________________________________________//

test_suite*
init_unit_test_suite( int argc, char* argv[] ) 
{
    if(/* is linux */)
        framework::master_test_suite().
            add( BOOST_TEST_CASE( &only_linux_test ) );

    return 0;
}
```

See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/test-organization/manual-nullary-test-case.html for more information

Another possibility would be to use #ifdef ... #endif with BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE.
Therfor you need a definition that is defined if you are compiling the code on the target platform.

```
#ifdef PLATFORM_IS_LINUX

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(onlyLinux)
{
    ...
}
#endif
```

This definition can for example be set by your build environment.

Comment: I can't use ifdefs, some of these criteria must be determine at execute-time.  I'll probably use something like your registration suggestion, thanks.

Answer (score 11):

`BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(a_test_name,`**[`*boost::unit_test::disabled()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/tests_organization/enabling.html)**`)`

```
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: I don't find this second parameter in the documentation, are you sure it is available?

Comment: totally yes http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/tests_organization/enabling.html

Comment: Cool thank you - and now i see that your second parameter was actually a link to the docs, doh.

Answer (score 8):

Use enable_if / enable / precondition decorators.

```
boost::test_tools::assertion_result is_linux(boost::unit_test::test_unit_id)
{
  return isLinux;
}


BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(MyTestSuite)

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(MyTestCase,
                     * boost::unit_test::precondition(is_linux))
{...}
```

precondition is evaluated at runtime, enable, enable_if at compile time.

See: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/tests_organization/enabling.html

Comment: Great! This is exactly what I was looking for (back in the day). I'll check it out with a couple of our tests.

Comment: @Horus, Is there a way to use a fixture in a precondition?

Comment: @mojo You can have a look at my code https://github.com/precice/precice/blob/develop/src/testing/Testing.hpp. I use a decorator to remove tests from the test tree, it might work for fixtures, too. Be advised, that my code likely uses unofficial boost API.

Answer (score 4):

Registering test cases manually is tedious, boring and error-prone.  If it is only by platform that you need to distinguish test cases, then I would simply not compile the irrelevant test cases on the platforms where they don't matter by configuring my build system.  Alternately, you can use [Boost.Predef](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/libs/predef/doc/html/index.html) that defines the necessary preprocessor symbols for everything you might want to know about OS, compiler, etc., that will allow you to `#ifdef` out certain tests.

Finally, if this criteria can only be known at runtime and is independent of the platform on which you're running then I would group the tests that depend on particular criteria into suites and adjust the command-line used by the build to run only those suites based on the runtime criteria.